# Admin role - user called null

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, admin

Each user has an admin role assigned to them. This admin role is required to show or hide widget.

I have an error message that the admin is called on null.

Despite getting user data for other widget, I the caller for Admin role is not being received properly from firebase.

```
  FirebaseUser currentUser;
  bool isAdmin= false;

    Widget adminFeature() {
    if(isAdmin == true) {
      return Text("You are an admin");
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }
```

```
  _getProfileData(User user,AuthNotifier authNotifier) async {
    final uid = await Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();
    await Provider.of(context)
        .db
        .collection('userData')
        .document(uid)
        .get().then((result) {
          user.isAdmin = result.data['isAdmin'];
    });
  }
```

```
              floatingActionButtonLocation: 
                FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
                  floatingActionButton:
                  FutureBuilder(
          future: _getProfileData(user, authNotifier),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              isAdmin = user.isAdmin ?? false;
            }
            return Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    backgroundColor:CompanyColors.blue[500],
                          child: const Icon(Icons.add),onPressed: () {
                              var foodNotifier = Provider.of<FoodNotifier>(context, listen: false);
                    foodNotifier.currentFood = null;
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return FoodForm(
                isUpdating: false,
              );
            }),
          );
        },
      ),
      adminFeature(),]
```

Comment: in _getProfileData in then use setState function and set isAdmin to true

Comment: thanks Benzo, where would you place the setState?

Comment: I assume you're using Statefull widget? You can set new variable data which will hold the data from API call. In statefull widget, you have method initState(). Within this function you'll call your function _getProfileData which will populate data variable. By that you will avoid having null variables, because vars will be populated immidiatly when building it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  _getProfileData(User user,AuthNotifier authNotifier) async {
    final uid = await Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();
    return await Provider.of(context)
        .db
        .collection('userData')
        .document(uid)
        .get();
  }
```

Then in the `FutureBuilder`:

```
  future: _getProfileData(user, authNotifier),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              isAdmin = snapshot.data['isAdmin'] ?? false;
            }
```

Return the result from the method and assign `result.data['isAdmin']` to the `isAdmin` variable.

Comment: the error is on the FutureBuilder, getter Admin was called on Null.

Comment: yes because `user` is null, which I removed in my code

Comment: this is the new error message: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("isAdmin")

Comment: in the `getProfileData()` do `print(uid)` and in the if clause do `print(snapshot.data)`

Comment: W/ProviderInstaller(25213): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
D/NetworkSecurityConfig(25213): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/ProviderInstaller(25213): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
D/ConnectivityManager(25213): requestNetwork; CallingUid : 10325, CallingPid : 25213
D/FirebaseAuth(25213): Notifying id token listeners about user ( kVfWOsHSbWhxFDeIqP6Gj8wXVKf1 ).

Comment: this has literally nothing to do with the print statements

Comment: the erro message, I receive in any case, Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError ('package:provider/src/provider.dart': Failed assertion: line 284 pos 7: 'T != dynamic': Tried to call Provider.of<dynamic>. This is likely a mistake and is therefore
unsupported.

If you want to expose a variable that can be anything, consider changing
`dynamic` to `Object` instead.
)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226777/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-j-l).